# KV script not working on pycharm on windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

Windows kivy works fine with

```
def build(self):
    return #object
```

but on running even official examples(PONG) with kv script it does not work!!

`I have tried Builder load`

Answer (score 0):

reinstalling helped for me maybe the release had some compatability issues